# How to add multiple suffixes for an integer field type?

Tags: views, entities

Is there a way to add multiple suffixes for an integer field type? For example, I want to input a value, and I want to be able to specify whether this is in inches or centimeters with a drop down box.

Is there a way to do this using only the field module?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options:

1. Install the [Measured Value Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mvf) module.
2. In your custom module implement `hook_form_alter` and add your dropdown there with markups.
3. Create actual dropdown and work with just markup.

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional field (apart from the integer field you already have), and make it a select list with possible values "*inches*" or "*centimeters*". With that, you don't have to install any other module (only the field module will do).

Optionally, you may want to group them together using the [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module (but that requires an extra module of course).