# How to Add Multiple Values to Prefix for Currency field as a Drop Down

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have a custom Decimal field, Salary, for one of my custom content type. How do I add multiple prefixes that I can display as a drop down in the node add/edit form for users to select their respective currencies while updating the salary field?

I have tried the currency module, however, I didn't find any option in it to add a decimal/ integer value in it.

Also tried Field Collection Module, it does give the option for combining multiple fields, but, the result looks a bit crude. The Fields come one above the other rather than alongside each other.

Is there any option for me to add Multiple prefixes in the Field and display the same as Drop Down List in the Node Add/Edit form?

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution in this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181799/how-to-add-multiple-suffixes-for-an-integer-field-type). Used the [Measured Value Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mvf) in Conjunction with [Units](https://www.drupal.org/project/units) and [Currency](https://www.drupal.org/project/currency). Got a pretty neat solution.